# Get all filenames of files in local directory with Javascript

Tags: php, html, file, flask

I am working on a website hosted on a Pi using flask.
I have a folder in which I am continuously adding jpg files.
I want to be able to check the files in the folder without having to refresh the page.
On the page I am using Javascript to show the files, I want to show the most recent image on the site.
Each image will have a file name like Rxxxxyyyyzzzz, where the x and y's are numbers containing some information about the images. The zzzz will just be an increment number, which i want to use for this.

This I expect to be ablt ot do with regular expressions, the issue is getting all the names of all files in the directory, so i can seach through it.

I found this php which should do that for me:

```
var files = <?php $out = array();
foreach (glob('file/*.jpg') as $filename) {
    $p = pathinfo($filename);
    $out[] = $p['filename'];
}

echo json_encode($out); ?>;
```

In the Html the src of the script should then be the file containing this. As such:

```
<Script src="/templates/dir.php" language="javascript">
//Code here
</Script>
```

But when i do this i get this warning and an error:

> The script from “http://192.168.137.210:2000/static/dir.php” was
>   loaded even though its MIME type (“application/octet-stream”) is not a
>   valid JavaScript MIME type.
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' dir.php:3:12

I dont really know any javascript or php for that matter, so any help is appreciated
​

Comment: Make php file and write the php code and include all files recursively.

`var files = <?php $out = array();
foreach (glob('file/*.jpg') as $filename) {
    $p = pathinfo($filename);
   echo '<Script src="'.$p['filename'].'" language="javascript"></Script>'
}
 ?>;`

Comment: in your `dir.php` you would likely want to include the correct header before any code. ie: `header('Content-Type: text/javascript');`

Answer (score 0):

`<Script src="/templates/dir.php" language="javascript">`

You are trying to execute a PHP script client-side. It can't work. The JS interpreter throws an error when it meets the PHP opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "/templates/dir.php",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(output) {
          console.log(output);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont know much about any of this, but does this not require a refresh of the page? Or can it check in a javascript function?

Comment: Nope, you don't have to refresh the page. Yes you put this code in a javascript function.

Comment: You need to inculde jQuery if you havn't done that.https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Comment: I tried this, but im getting no output at all. No errors either, so i have no idea what the issue is. I tried changing the file path, but no changes

Comment: Jup, its like everything inside the ajax block is just being skipped. Tried adding some console.logs inside there, and none of them are being logged at any point

Comment: If you put a console log next to the Ajax script. Does it get executed?

Comment: The one before and after both get logged

Comment: And you have included jQuery?

Comment: Yes, i have. Figured out an other way to get the functionality i wanted, but i still very much would like to get this to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you could accomplish your stated aim, I created two working versions using different approaches. The following uses `AJAX` to query the server every few seconds and is probably the easiest approach. The problem with any long-polling ajax is the amount of traffic it generates but in some cases this will not be an issue.

In the question you show how you tried to include a PHP script within a Javascript tag as an external file. This is possible but you need to specify the `Content-Type` header in the php file ( as `text/javascript` or similar ). That said, PHP runs once and then terminates before any client-side code is invoked so the contents of said javascript(PHP) file would be static - how would you get new file info??

If you use Ajax the page does not need to be reloaded to obtain the new file info - you schedule the ajax function to run every X seconds and use the callback function to manipulate the DOM and display the image.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();

        $path=explode( '/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] );
        array_pop( $path );     


        $dir=__DIR__ . '/images/tmp';   #   sub-directory of current working directory
        $path=implode( '/', $path );    #   suitable path for use in displaying images - root relative


        /* scan the directory for jpg, jpeg and png images */
        $col=preg_grep( '@(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)@i', glob( $dir . '/*.*' ) );


        /* Most recent file - sort array by comparing file modification timestamps */
        usort( $col, function( $a, $b ){
            return filemtime( $a ) < filemtime( $b ) ? 1 : 0;
        });


        /* tweak the sorted array to create suitable image paths */
        array_walk( $col, function( &$item, $key ) use ( $path ){
            $item=str_replace( __DIR__, $path, $item );
        });     


        $payload=array(
            'latest'    =>  array_shift( $col ),
            'oldest'    =>  array_pop( $col )
        );


        exit( json_encode( $payload, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Directory monitor using ajax</title>
        <script>

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                const output=document.querySelector('output');
                const image=document.querySelector('img');
                const span=document.querySelector('span');

                const loadimage=function( url ){
                    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{
                        let img=new Image();
                            img.onload=resolve( img );
                            img.onerror=reject( new Error( `Bogus!\n\nUnable to load ${url}` ) );
                            img.src=url;
                    });
                };
                const ajax=function(url,callback){
                    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback( this.response )
                    };
                    xhr.onerror=function(e){
                        alert(e)
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                    xhr.send();
                };
                const ajaxcallback=function(r){
                    let json=JSON.parse( r );
                    if( json.latest!=null ){
                        loadimage( json.latest ).then( img=>{ image.src=img.src } ).catch( err=>{ alert(err) } );
                    }
                };

                /* anonymous, self-executing function to re-query every X seconds or whatever... */
                (function(){
                    ajax( location.href, ajaxcallback )
                    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 * 5 );
                })();

            });
        </script>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Directory Monitor using ajax</h1>
            <output></output>
            <span><img /></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above looks at a sub-directory of the `current working directory` called images and was tested by copying new files into said directory on a regular basis and this worked well so long as the newly copied files had their `Last Modified` time set to the time of the copy operation - `filemtime` afterall gets file modification time.

```
/ monitor.php
└─
   images/
         └─
            pic1.jpg
            pic2.jpg
```

The other approach I tried ( and prefer ) would be to use an `EventSource` connection that uses PHP in an infinite loop to query your directory and send back messages. This uses a single connection from Javascript to the PHP script which stays open as long as the page is open ( or until explicitly killed )